# Regular expression to exclude part of a url?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to create a regular expression for google analytics goals.

I need to match either of these 2 url fragments:

`/order/map/egw/?code=somevalue`

or

`/order/map/egw/`

But NOT this url:

`/order/map/egw/consult/`

Tried this:

`/order/map/egw/$ | /order/map/egw/\?`

and other variations but can't get it to match properly

Fast help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be looking for regex lookarounds.

Answer (score 1):

How about this regular expression?

```
/order/map/egw/(?!consult).*
```

If in the future you find that there's another sub-directory that you don't want to include, you can add a new one (e.g. the sub-directory 'wrong') like so:

```
/order/map/egw/(?!consult|wrong).*
```

Comment: @user3642171 Great! Would you like to mark my answer as the correct one? :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this? I don't know how strict you're trying to be but it should work for your use cases:

```
(?!.*consult)/order/map/egw/(\?.+)?
```

It ensures "consult" is not found in the URL and matches the base part with an optional query string.

Comment: Thanks. Yours works too but the one below is a little cleaner. Appreciate the help.